# Sharepoint 2010 - Is a workflow the simplest way to send mail notifications?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, alert

I have inherited a Sharepoint 2010 site. I have found a simple "list" with a few custom fields that the company used before and wants to use again. A new list item SHOULD generate an email with the fields, and send it to a certain user. (All mails should go to the same user). Is a workflow the simplest way to do this? Or is there a way for the user to set an email Alert containing the custom fields when a new item is submitted.

I currently can't see the list in Sharepoint Designer, though I can access it and submit new items on the site itself. I am thinking this is a permissions issue and am trying to track down a Site Owner. I am a farm administrator but can't see the site owners. I have tried stsadm, which  didn't work, and a powershell script that showed all sites and subsites, but the owner was showing as blank.

Comment: Change the Site Owner of the site to yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a Workflow Task list, then the OOB Alert feature should work nicely for this. Go to List > Settings > Advanced Settings > E-Mail Notification. It works with custom fields, too. If this is not your scenario, then I would use workflow.

Regarding  SharePoint Designer permissions: since you are a farm admin, add yourself as a site collection administrator in central admin (Application Management > Change Site Collection Administrators), and you should be set for all sites in that site collection. Also make sure to enable SharePoint designer. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592376

Comment: I was able to see a service account there, and only 1 is allowed, so I let it be. I logged in as the service account and added myself to the Site Owners group. There's half my issue fixed!   Under List Settings -> Advanced Settings, I do NOT see E-mail notification. I searched every single option under "List Settings" - no luck. Under "Workflow settings", there are no workflows assigned. Under "List Permissions", I can see that the user that should get the emails does have permission and is able to see the list contents. I just need to get that e-mail sent! What am I missing?

Comment: When logged in as the service account, you can add additional site collection admins under site settings > Site collection administrators. Regarding the e-mail notifications setting I mentioned: That is only available in the "Workflow Tasks" list in your workflow-enabled site. The OOTB list alerts on other lists (@yandr mentioned them) will send a notification that an item has changed, but will not include the custom fields you described in your question.

Comment: To do that, you could make a custom alert template: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx) or just make a custom workflow which runs when a list item is created. If it were me, I would go the workflow route - it is simpler

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for your particular case the OOTB email alerts is the easiest option.

If you cannot see the option, maybe you need to [configure alert settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262816(v=office.14).aspx) for a Web application by using Central Administration:

- Verify that the user account that is performing this task is a member
  of the Farm Administrators SharePoint group.
- On the SharePoint Central Administration Web site, click Application
  Management.
- On the Application Management page, click Manage Web Applications.
- Click the Web application for which you want to configure alerts.
- On the ribbon, click the General Settings drop-down menu, and then
  click General Settings
- On the Web Application General Settings page, in the Alerts section,
  configure the  settings
- Click OK